# Multiple items form referring to a specific field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a multiple item form which takes records from a table:
[image]

this edit button I added in Design view , I want to be able to refer to the record which the button is bound to , like really simple task as msgbox this record ID

Comment: That ID will be `Me!ID.Value`. But having all those Edit buttons is a little "webish" style design.

Comment: Every row you select becomes the current record.

Comment: thank you all for your answers, @Gustav I don't know how the right design should be .. my background is web development yeah :)

Comment: OK. We don't know the context, so just go ahead.